# streaming videos on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, video-streaming

I want to stream large videos from ftp in iPhone. The video are in size more then 500 MB. I have never done streaming so have no idea about it. I have checked live streaming guide from Apple but it does not provide any help regarding coding in iPhone. Can some one help me what exactly I have to do in iPhone coding? So far I have done following:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.defencecourse.com/digital-reproductions/yellow-belt.mp4"]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
[mpvc release];
```

Is this coding enough to play a streaming video?

I have a guy who prepare videos for me what should I exactly ask him to do with videos on the server? Should I ask him just to split videos on server or something else? 
Can Someone please suggest me best way to forward?

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

Check these tutorials [AVFoundation Tutorials](http://www.sdkboy.com/?cat=8) and read out the Apple's AVFoundation Framework programming guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

AVFoundation Framework is much more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have to do following things on iphone side ...

-(void) btnClose_clicked {

```
[appDelegate.navShowController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}
-(IBAction) btnPlay_clicked {

```
//    NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
//   NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self.DiscAnsDetail objectForKey:@"product_video"]];  
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];  

// Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                           object:moviePlayer];  

if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {  
    // Use the new 3.2 style API  
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;  
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];  
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];  
} else {  
    // Use the old 2.0 style API  
    moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;  
    [moviePlayer play];  
}
```

}
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayer];

```
// If the moviePlayer.view was added to the view, it needs to be removed  
if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {  
    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];  
}  

[moviePlayer release];
```

}